# Longest subarray with sum at most K

Tags: algorithms

The question is:

> Return the length of the longest, non-empty, contiguous subarray of A with sum at most K.
>
> For example: A=[5,2,-1,0,3],K=1, the result is [2,-1,0]

I am inspired by [Shortest Subarray with Sum at Least K](https://leetcode.com/problems/shortest-subarray-with-sum-at-least-k). Is it possible to solve this corresponding problem with a monotonic queue? If True, how? If not, Why?

I have struggled with it for a long time. Hope for your help.

Comment: It's tricky, because you have negative numbers in the array. If the sum of the first n-1 elements is H for some huge H, then the last element could be -H, making the sum 0.

Comment: Hint: Suppose you know the length of the longest subarray with sum at most $k$ that ends at position $i$, and the sum of this subarray. How to find the length of the longest subarray with sum at most $k$ that ends at position $i+1$, and its sum? Note: This only needs to take *amortised* constant time for linear runtime overall.